# Structures and typedefs and pointers in C

Tags: c

I am trying create a doubly linked list in C and I have a question regarding the code below:

```
typedef struct Node{

   double coeff;
   int exp;
   struct Node* next;
   struct Node* prev;

}Node;
```

*My question*:

In line(5) above; Is it correct to say that I am creating a pointer variable called next? And this variable is of type Node? This variable will point to the address of the next Node stored in memory?

Is the Node* the same as Node *pointer?

Thanks for the help; I want to get my foundation solid before I progress further.

Comment: yes, but you have to make sure it will point to the address of the next Node stored in memory. and the spaces before or after `*` do not make a difference for it's meaning.

Comment: `next` is of type `struct Node*` (a pointer to a `struct Node`). It doesn't point to valid memory unless you set it.

Comment: In C, you've defined a type `struct Node`, and you use that during the definition of the structure body.  The alias (`typedef`) name `Node` is not defined until the last semicolon; it cannot be used before that.  If you are asking about the difference between `struct Node *next;` and `struct Node* next;`, the only difference is in the spacing.  However, be aware that if you wrote `struct Node *next, *prev;`, both `next` and `prev` are pointers; by contrast, if you wrote `struct Node* next, prev;`, then `next` is a pointer, but `prev` is a plain `struct Node`, not a pointer.

Comment: `next` is a pointer of type `struct Node *`, which, after the typedef, can also be called `Node *`. `Node` is a structure type, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks 'Wimmel', Does that mean that I should initially set it to null when I create a new node and only assign a value to it, if that value is the address of the next node.

Comment: That's generally the way it's done.

Comment: Thanks for that guys, I have reformatted the typedef discrepancy by making all the 'Nodes', 'nodes' except for the last one between the '}' and the ';'. It is way cleaner that way. I would have taken me ages to spot that struct* next prev; is a pointer variable called next but that prev would just be a variable of type node. Which is no good for me in this case since I want to have variables of type node (type node because pointers must point to the same type as themselves). Just wondering what you would suggest regarding a function to create a new node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In line(5) above; Is it correct to say that I am creating a pointer variable called next?*

You have defined a type `struct Node` with a member named `next`( and others ).

*And this variable is of type Node?,*

`next` has a type `struct Node*`

*This variable will point to the address of the next Node stored in memory?*

If you assign it a correct value then it will.